# How to correctly use maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true) in Spring STOMP websocket?

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket

A have a Spring boot websocket server, which I reduced to a bare bone echo-server to reproduce my problem. My real application is a calculation engine (server) which users access via a JavaFx client. I want that user is authenticated, authorized, and can have only one active session.

Authentication and authorization more or less work, apart that I am using the deprecated class `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` which later I would love to replace with state of the art approach.

To limit the sessions, I am trying to use `maximumSessions(1)` and `maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)` to block users from connecting more than once. I am clearly new to Spring so made some attempts. Basically I get two results:

1 - The configuration does not work at all, the user can log in as many times as he likes, despite maximumSessions(1) and maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)

2 - The user connects and logs in normally, other simultaneous connections are not allowed (as expected) but, if user disconnects (e.g. closes the client), he is not allowed to log in again. I would expect that a user can re-connect to the server after disconnection. I log authentication and session events so I can see that user is properly authenticated but a new session apparently is not created and the response code is 401.

What is that I am missing to have the proper configuration?

The web security configuration is as as follows

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .sessionConcurrency((concurrency) -> concurrency
                            .maximumSessions(1)
                            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                    )
        );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

for websockets the security configuration is as simple as

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages.anyMessage().hasRole("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    return true;
  }

@Bean
  public UserDetailsService users() {
    User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
    UserDetails user1 = users
            .username("user1")
            .password("secret")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
    UserDetails user2 = users
            .username("user2")
            .password("secret")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
    UserDetails admin = users
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2, admin);
  }
}
```

any hint is very appreciated.
I will include here below more information on the example.

The message broker:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer  {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/myEndpoint");
  }

}
```

A trivial controller

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GreetingController.class);

  @MessageMapping("/hello")
  @SendToUser("/topic/greetings")
  public MyMessage greeting(MyMessage myMessage) throws Exception {
    MyMessage response = new MyMessage();
    response.setContent("Server response: " + myMessage.getContent());
    return response;
  }
}
```

The testing is done with a simple Java client, the relevant part is the following

```
    WebSocketContainer webSocketContainer = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient(webSocketContainer);
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();

    WebSocketHttpHeaders httpHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
    StompHeaders stompHeaders = null;

    // Basic HTTP authentication
    String userData = "user1" + ":" + "secret";

    String auth = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userData.getBytes());
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", auth);

    String endpointUrl = "ws://localhost:8080/myEndpoint";

    CompletableFuture<StompSession> newSession =
            stompClient.connectAsync(endpointUrl, httpHeaders, stompHeaders, sessionHandler);

    StompSession session;
    try {
      session = newSession.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I enabled debug logging as suggested by toerktumlare.
The following configuration does not work (case 1), user can login any amount of times:

```
.sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions
        .sessionConcurrency((concurrency) -> concurrency
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        )
);
```

The following configuration works, client connects but a concurrent attempt of connection fails:

```
.sessionManagement((sessions) -> sessions
         .maximumSessions(1)
         .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)

);
```

The problem is that if the client is disconnected (client app closed), it is not allowed to reconnect to the server. In the immense log which unfortunately is too long to be accepted in the forum, I identified the reason:

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded
```

*I guess that even if the client was disconnected, the session somehow persisted so the server still sees and open session and then does not allow a new one.*

The complete log of the server is immense, I will report here only a small part:

```
2023-08-29T18:14:49.978+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : StandardWebSocketSession[id=b197502e-f51a-9ecc-6656-81734edb6067, uri=ws://localhost:8080/myEndpoint] closed with CloseStatus[code=1006, reason=null]
2023-08-29T18:14:49.978+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : Clearing session b197502e-f51a-9ecc-6656-81734edb6067
2023-08-29T18:14:49.980+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.m.a.i.ChannelSecurityInterceptor   : Authorized GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=DISCONNECT, stompCommand=DISCONNECT, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpUser=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=aValidUser, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], simpSessionId=b197502e-f51a-9ecc-6656-81734edb6067}] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
2023-08-29T18:14:49.982+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nboundChannel-8] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Processing DISCONNECT session=b197502e-f51a-9ecc-6656-81734edb6067
2023-08-29T18:14:49.983+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting down[http-nio-8080-exec-4] latch=1
2023-08-29T18:14:49.984+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@791acff6].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4ad4742e:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@64816dd6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:55274]])
2023-08-29T18:14:49.984+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [tboundChannel-2] o.s.w.s.m.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler    : No session for GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=DISCONNECT_ACK, simpDisconnectMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=DISCONNECT, stompCommand=DISCONNECT, simpSessionAttributes={org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpAttributes.COMPLETED=true}, simpUser=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=aValidUser, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], simpSessionId=b197502e-f51a-9ecc-6656-81734edb6067}], simpUser=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=aValidUser, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], simpSessionId=b197502e-f51a-9ecc-6656-81734edb6067}]
2023-08-29T18:14:49.985+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.h.u.UpgradeProcessorInternal       : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4ad4742e:Closed NioChannel], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.276+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [o-8080-Acceptor] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting up[http-nio-8080-Acceptor] latch=1
2023-08-29T18:14:51.276+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Before fill(): parsingHeader: [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [0], byteBuffer.limit(): [0], end: [210]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.277+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1449bd4f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@64816dd6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:55276]], Read from buffer: [0]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.277+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1449bd4f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@64816dd6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:55276]], Read direct from socket: [210]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.277+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /myEndpoint HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YVZhbGlkVXNlcjpzZWNyZXQ=
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 7T+Cabz/6S2ksp4g3zFEoA==
Connection: upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Host: localhost:8080
Upgrade: websocket

]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.278+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /myEndpoint
2023-08-29T18:14:51.278+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2023-08-29T18:14:51.278+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2023-08-29T18:14:51.278+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /myEndpoint
2023-08-29T18:14:51.351+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-08-29T18:14:51.351+02:00  INFO 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.example.server.AuthenticationEvents    : AUTHENTICATION SUCCESS: org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent[source=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=aValidUser, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.351+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=aValidUser, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.351+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2023-08-29T18:14:51.352+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : SessionAuthenticationStrategy rejected the authentication object

org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.allowableSessionsExceeded(ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]

  ...some other stuff...

2023-08-29T18:14:51.353+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : Sending 401 Unauthorized error
2023-08-29T18:14:51.353+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.355+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-08-29T18:14:51.356+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2023-08-29T18:14:51.357+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2023-08-29T18:14:51.367+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-08-29T18:14:51.384+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.385+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue Aug 29 18:14:51 CEST 2023, status=401, error=Unauthorized, path=/myEndpoint}]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.414+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 401
2023-08-29T18:14:51.415+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for further output
2023-08-29T18:14:51.415+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Before fill(): parsingHeader: [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [0], byteBuffer.limit(): [0], end: [210]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.416+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1449bd4f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@64816dd6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:55276]], Read from buffer: [0]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.416+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1449bd4f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@64816dd6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:55276]], Read direct from socket: [0]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.416+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received []
2023-08-29T18:14:51.416+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1449bd4f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@64816dd6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:55276]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.416+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1449bd4f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@64816dd6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:55276]]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.417+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Before fill(): parsingHeader: [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [0], byteBuffer.limit(): [0], end: [210]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.417+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1449bd4f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@64816dd6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:55276]], Read from buffer: [0]
2023-08-29T18:14:51.417+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
    ...some other stuff...

2023-08-29T18:14:51.418+02:00 DEBUG 50484 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
  ...some other stuff...
```

The stack trace of the client is the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: Failed to handle HTTP response code [401]. Missing [WWW-Authenticate] header in response
    at com.example.client.App.main(App.java:54)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: Failed to handle HTTP response code [401]. Missing [WWW-Authenticate] header in response
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at com.example.client.App.main(App.java:52)
Caused by: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: Failed to handle HTTP response code [401]. Missing [WWW-Authenticate] header in response
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.processAuthenticationChallenge(WsWebSocketContainer.java:487)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:379)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: Failed to handle HTTP response code [401]. Missing [WWW-Authenticate] header in response

    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.lambda$executeInternal$0(StandardWebSocketClient.java:150)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$toSupplier$0(FutureUtils.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
Caused by: jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: Failed to handle HTTP response code [401]. Missing [WWW-Authenticate] header in response
```

The test project is available here https://github.com/kartegy/spring-stomp-websocket-security

Comment: `.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` if your server is stateless, how can the server know that there are multiple sessions out there, since you have told it to not keep any state of how many sessions that exist?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, get your point. Anyway, I don't get the expected result regardless of how session creation policy is configured. I can remove the explicit configuration, which should default to `IF_REQUIRED`, I can set it to `ALWAYS`... Same result: server accepts only the first connection, following attempts fail. So my question remains: how shall I fix my configuration?

Comment: without more information, logs requests a working example its impossible for us to help you, good luck

Comment: Please use something like github as me and many other will not download a random blob from a file share because of security reasons.

Comment: I will create an account and do that asap. Anyway I updated the post with most of the information but the gradle project is indeed easier to inspect and test

Comment: please enable debug logs or trace logs and show us the full logs, you explanation does not really make sense, you connect and then disconnect and then connect again? if you restart the server the session is lost and you need to authenticate again

Comment: Created github repo https://github.com/kartegy/spring-stomp-websocket-security will try to improve the order later. I am clearly totally new in Spring but maybe it can be turned into a useful example for others like me, am I really investing days and days if figuring this out. I will try to collect more logs and edit the post to make the explanation clearer

Comment: Updated the post with additional info and the repo with better tests. Hope this will help, thanks